# Changing the background color and the main content background in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I've been searching on this topic for almost 1 hour and I couldn't find an answer, as you know most youtube videos out there are completely useless. My website is on WordPress and I would like to change the background color, and the main content in **specific pages**

Here's the code that I tried to add to the Custom CSS box

```
.page-id-2
{
background: #FFFFFF
}

.page-id-2 .content {
background: #FFFFFF
}
```

It didn't do anything

Here my website: www.graspdating.com

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The selector you want is an ID (`#`) not a Class (`.`)

**EDIT**

```
.page-id-2 #content, 
.page-id-2 #content article,
.page-id-2 #content #search-2,
.page-id-2 #content .enl-widget-title,
.page-id-2 #content #secondary,
.page-id-2 #content .arc-entry-meta { background-color: #FFFFFF }
```

This should completely "white-out" the background of the content area. If there are certain elements you want to have a different color, you can remove accordingly.

Comment: That changed the background color, the content area is still the same

Comment: The "content area" I am assuming you are talking about is in an `article` element. So you would use the same logic. `.page-id-2 #content, .page-id-2 #content article { background-color: #FFFFFF }` . Just a note, there are several element on your page that may need to be targeted to change the background completely white.

Comment: If you are familiar with Developer Tools in your browser you can view the DOM and fiddle around with the CSS of the elements there. If this answered your question could you please mark my answer as accepted ?

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override the current class properties using another class properties. There are different ways in which properties can be overridden. Assuming you have the following for your `.site-content`:

```
.blog .site-content { background: #eeeeee;}
```

e.g. any of the following would override it:

```
.blog .site-content { background: red !important;}
body .blog .site-content { background: red;}
.page-id-2 .blog .site-content { background: red;}
body.page-id-2 .blog .site-content { background: red;}
```

the first one "wins" by !important, a blunt instrument... The rest “win” by selector specificity;

By saying that, you can override properties by the selector specificity (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) and/or using the `!important` (https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit confusing, LegenJerry gave me a simple code which I've added to the Custom CSS box, and it did actually change the background color on that page, but the main content background is still the same, is there any code I can add?

Comment: I'm trying to explain to you the logic of overriding properties on CSS. If you just copy and paste a code without understand what is going on, it will not help you to learn. If you use the dev tools on the browser you will be able to check why the background have not changed (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools). So set your element `.enl-page` the desired background, use this code `.post2.enl-page{ background: red; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it using dependency like

body .page-id-2 { background: #FFFFFF; }

similarly you can also use

body.page-id-63 #content { background: #FFFFFF; }